# Detect Typical Customer Mistakes in the Shopping Cart

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I would like to ask your advice on solving this problem.

**Problem**

There is an online store which sells furniture. There are millions of products on the store like furniture parts and furniture itself. Customers in this store usually do the same issues when purchasing products:

- accidentally add one/two products in an absolutely different style/color/wood type than the rest of items
- accidentally duplicate qty of products. Let's say there are products which typically purchase in qty of 1 or 2
  We need to be able to find this kind of issues in shopping carts and notify customers why and where they have issues, in our opinion.

We can use store lifetime order history, but there are no labeled entities. However, we may assume that some set of orders are correct.

**My Thoughts**

It seems like a Neural Network may be a good solution here. We need to analyze different count of items per cart. Count of product items in a cart can be really different: from 1 to 100. It looks like RNN can help here. BTW, is there any alternatives?

RNN pays attention to the order of sequence items. I think the position of products in the shopping cart is not really important. Different people may start purchasing their bedrooms from different sides. Is it going to be an issue?

Also, a good question is data processing. We have just set of products per shopping cart/order that were added/purchased. Each cart/order item has qty and product. Each product has different features like styles, colors, wood type. Count of possible product is huge. How to convert all this information for NN?

From examples I saw, people usually try to feed just a list of numbers to NN. It's hard to understand how can we transform all of cart item features to the plain array. Any thoughts about this?

How to formalize this problem? I see it as the anomaly detection on a sequence of data with multiple features. Do you think it's fair?

Finally, how to get more information about founded issues then 'this shopping cart is incorrect'? Ideally, we need to be able to say that this chair has a different color than the rest of the items and that wardrobe is not purchased in such qty usually.

How would you tackle such a problem? Any advice, suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a model at all? You can just enumerate the colors of all the items in the cart and check if they are all the same. If not, there's a mismatch. Likewise, you can count if the number of items is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the first idea to don't use ANN and use kind of statistic methods. However, counts of patterns to check can be more than we can realize. Just an example, there can be "valid" shopping cart with two product colors. So the second idea was to feed already existing "valid" shopping carts to ANN and let it find those patterns and relations

Comment: How could you know the cart with 2 or more product colors is valid if you don't have any labels? How do you know that some combinations are valid and some aren't? It seems like person A might make a mistake and have a mismatch but person B deliberately wants 2 different colors, and their shopping carts could be exactly identical.

Comment: With such an abstract explanation of products, it may be hard to get this, but products are not really independent. There are domain relations between then and using this knowledge domain expert can determine whenever this set of products are purchased with intention or accidentally. Let's say, some kind of molding makes sense to buy with this kind of cabinets. So generally speaking, it would be great to learn from the data and to be able to help domain experts to automate routine

Comment: I think it's still possible to detect false positive because there are always exceptions that will be hard to cover even by domain expert. However, it should be okay if ANN just triggers to show a notice about its decision concerning the current shopping cart

Comment: So answering the how question, I would say that the domain expert would check if there are any reasons to buy products of each style. The expert knows some patterns, relations, typical things about the domain which help him to see "intention" behind  the purchase